# multithread autorelease issue with ARC?

Tags: ios, multithreading, automatic-ref-counting, atomic

A class of service has a nonatomic property which is set in a serial queue.

```
@interface Service
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *status;
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t queue;
...
@end

- (void)update:(NSDicationary *)paramDict {
    dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
        ....
        self.status = updateDict;
    }
}


- (void)someMethod {
    NSDictionary *status = self.status;
}
```

The app crashed when the getter was invoked, at `objc_autorelease + 6`, which seems to be a runtime/Clang/llvm invocation.

And the crash log also showed that the `status` property was just set on the `queue` thread.

Did it crash because of the lack of atomicity in the accessors? If yes, how and why the getter failed retaining the instance? Did the autorelease pool get drained inside the synthesized nonatomic setter?

Should I implement the getter/setter method, protecting it with `queue`/a mutex lock?

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `atomic` can address some integrity issues of fundamental data types in multi-threaded code, it's not sufficient to achieve thread-safety in general. Thread-safety is generally achieved through the judicious use of locks or queues. See the [Synchronization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) section of the *Threading Programming Guide.* Or see [Eliminating Lock-Based Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) of the *Concurrency Programming Guide* that describes the use of queues in lieu of synchronization locks.

Assuming your queue is serial, you might be able to make it thread-safe by using the following construct:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    dispatch_sync(self.queue, ^{

        NSDictionary *status = self.status;

        // do what you need to with status
    });
}
```

That way, you're effectively using your serial queue to synchronize access to the `status` dictionary.

By the way, if your queue is a custom concurrent, you might also want to make sure that you replace the `dispatch_async` in `paramDict` to be `dispatch_barrier_async`. If your queue is serial, then `dispatch_async` is fine.

I'd suggest you try synchronizing your access to `status`, either using your queue or one of the synchronization techniques described in the *Threading Programming Guide.*

Comment: I agree that a dispatch queue is generally good in such situation. However, I am not completely sure wether the crash was caused by violation of thread safety or not.

Comment: @ZhangChn Oh, yes, I agree. I apologize for neglecting that fairly fundamental point. The source of the exception is not at all clear. I was just reacting to the focus on atomic v nonatomic. Having said that, it's worth making this thread-safe: You have to do that anyway and it may fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, change the code like this.

nonatomic -> atomic

Comment: I have little experience using atomic property on iOS as it was recommended not to. How does `atomic` affect the behavior of accessor methods on iOS exactly?

Comment: Wait, I should check it out. Thank for your response.